# Symfony2 - Different services, same arguments - how to avoid duplication

Tags: symfony

I have one controller defined as service and it has different arguments.

It's something like this:

```
   <service id="my.controller" class="%my.controller.class%">
       <argument type="service" id="form.factory"/>
       <argument type="service" id="templating"/>
       <argument type="service" id="router"/>
       <argument type="service" id="validator"/>
        <call method="setEntityManager">
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
       </call>
       <call method="getExpenseRepository">
            <argument>Expense</argument>
       </call>
   </service>
```

Now I need another controller, which will use the same arguments like the one above. What to do to avoid writing this again with only changing the service id and class?

And one more thing - in the first controller I have:

```
private $formFactory;
private $templating;
private $router;
private $validator;

public function __construct($formFactory, $templating, $router, $validator)
{
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->templating = $templating;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Can I avoid rewriting it in the second one?

Thanks very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and specify a common parent service to reduce repetition :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html

You can also define an abstract controller class.

Your child controllers will only need to extends this class and call the parent service.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an abstract parent service and inherit the other services from it, a sample config would be

```
   <service id="my.parentcontroller" class="%my.parentcontroller.class%"  abstract="true">
     <argument type="service" id="form.factory"/>
     <argument type="service" id="templating"/>
     <argument type="service" id="router"/>
     <argument type="service" id="validator"/>
      <call method="setEntityManager">
          <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
     </call>
     <call method="getExpenseRepository">
          <argument>Expense</argument>
     </call>
   </service>

<service id="my.controller1" class="%my.controller1.class%" parent="my.parentcontroller"/>
<service id="my.controller2" class="%my.controller2.class%" parent="my.parentcontroller"/>
```

Also your controllers classes should inherit from the abstract parent controller.